# Is it a good idea to upload my private key to VPS / servers?

Tags: ssh, private-key

Saying if I am deploying my application to the server using git, and the repository needs authentication to be pulled, it will be very convenient if I just upload my private key there.

However is it a good idea to do so?

Comment: Use a second keypair, which has only read-only access to the git repository.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton That's really a good idea. But sad thing is it's not easy to be done using GitHub.

Comment: I add multiple keys into github all the time.  Why do you say it isn't easy?

Comment: If you're checking out from a public github repo you don't need keys at all? And from a private repo you only need to add another keypair as a [read-only deploy key](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/).

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the private key you use to authenticate to your server, then absolutely not. That key needs to truly stay private, never leaving your machine, and definitely encrypted with a passcode. If you need to deploy software from your server, then generate a separate key pair for that purpose, that has severely restricted privileges on the systems its deploying from.